# IBM DB2, stored procedure with ALIAS as parameter

Tags: sql, db2, alias, ibm-midrange

I am on a (AS/400, iSeries, PowerI or whatever) box.
I am trying to develop a stored procedure that creates an ALIAS for a database member, use that alias for a select into , and finally drop the alias.

I am geting SQL error code SQL0204 (ie-file or member not found) then calling the procedure .

There is a note in the sql reference manual that says:

> If a member is specified, the alias cannot be used in most SQL schema
>   statements. It can be used in CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE FUNCTION and in
>   a CREATE TABLE with an as-result-table clause

I don't understand what the "as-result-table" means, or how to code it.

My code is like this:

```
create procedure targetlib/check_sql                             
( IN MEMBERNAME CHAR(10))                                       
LANGUAGE SQL                                                  
DETERMINISTIC                                                 
MODIFIES SQL DATA                                             
BEGIN                                                         
  Create ALIAS targetlib/table544 for targetfile( MEMBERNAME );
  INSERT INTO targetlib/receiver (                             
    SELECT * FROM targetlib/table544                             
    WHERE field1='SOMETHING' AND field2 = 'ELSE'                       
  );                                                          
    DROP ALIAS targetlib/table544;                               
END;
```

Solved: It must be totally dynamic sql, otherwise it will not work. 
If i code like this( I can't use || for concatenation):

```
set sql_string = CONCAT('create alias targetlib/table544 for targetfile(', CONCAT(MEMBER, ')'));  
PREPARE S1 from sql_string;
execute S1;
```

I works. Thank's to [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) who pointed med in the right direction.

Comment: You would need to do this using dynamic SQL.

Comment: I tried this:`code` declare sql_string char(1024); set sql_string = create alias blabla for lib/file( & ); PREPARE S1 from sql_string; execute S1 using MEMBER; in the procedure, but it did'nt work as excpected.

Comment: . . You can edit your question and add that code in the question.

Comment: Ok, thats make sense. I will add in my edits. Thanks.

Comment: Does this dynamic sql work with an alias in qtemp.  It would solve a great deal of collision problems creating in targetlib with the same name.

Comment: Is there a reason to use ALIAS over an OVRDBF? Creating an ALIAS implies also authorities, etc., and allows other processes to run into it accidentally; while OVRDBF keeps it within this job.

Comment: I used ALIAS over OVRDBF to have an all-in-one sql solution.In our production box all programs MUST go thru code-review and test, but sql is seen as reporting.